# Whats the Best option for NestedSet ( MPTT ) Implementation in Zend Framework Zend_Db?

Tags: php

Whats the Best option for NestedSet ( MPTT ) Implementation in Zend Framework Zend_Db ?
By Default It doesnt supports it which is a bit strange IMHO because Symfony/CakePHP have that built-in. parent_id (Adjacency List) is very slow due to recursion I think so thats not an option for Hierarchial Data .

Is there any unofficial MPTT Implementation or I have to replace Zend_Db with Doctrine Altogether ?

Please share if anybody had an Experience like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Db tends to be pretty versatile, but also remember that each zend component acts as a module in its own right, so you should be able to easily replace Zend_Db with Doctrine.